# pyqt gui application packaging for ubuntu

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, pyqt, packaging

I am really new to packaging.
I have developed a music player using pyqt in ubuntu.
It has a gui and it uses sqlite database.

I have looked at distutil.
What I understood is how to place modules and scripts in right place.
What I don't understand is how to set paths for database, config files & log files.
How do I achieve it the way other applications do it in ubuntu by maintainig all this data in '.application_name' folder under home for a user ?

Can anyone suggest a good example application to learn from or point in some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QDir.home() to get the absolute path to a user's home path. You can use this path when generating/accessing your database, config files and log files. For example, on first startup you can do something like:

```
filePath = QDir.home() + "/.application_name"
if not QDir.exists(filepath)
    QDir.mkdir(filepath)
```

Then you can use filePath when reading/writing to the files from there on out.

Comment: You should use os.path.join(QDir.home().absolutePath(), ".application_name"), so it works cross-platform. I know the question was about Ubuntu, but if it's successful someone will want it to run on Windows